# Create Waze links in web page

Tags: waze

I want to build links in my web page to open in Waze.
I have a DB with my customers addresses (not the GPS or Lat/Long) and want to click on the link and open Waze with the directions to the address.

Answer (score 0):

This should be relatively easy to do with the [Waze Deeplinks](https://developers.google.com/waze/deeplinks) feature. The deep links work differently depending on which environment you're on (see below), which should be fine in your use case.

Basically, when you link someone to `https://waze.com/ul?q=some%20address`, the Waze site will then take the appropriate action:

- Desktop: shows a page that allows you to send the location to a mobile device
- Mobile (with Waze installed): open the app and start the search with the entered arguments
- Mobile (without Waze installed): open as the live map with a link to the the Play Store or App Store to install Waze

There's the argument `&navigate=yes` you could add to the URL to start the navigation directly. But from my experience that only seems to have an effect if you provide exact coordinates to navigate to, which you mention you don't have.